# how to add user role in php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to redirect my users and admin to some certain pages but my php code is redirecting both the admin and users to the same page

```
if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['surname'];
    $password_hash = md5($password);
    $role;
    if (!empty($username) && (!empty($password))) 
    {
    $query = "SELECT 'id' FROM users WHERE 'staffno' = '$username' AND 'password'='$password_hash'";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if ($run) {
         $sql = "SELECT users.role FROM users";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
          $user = mysqli_fetch_array( $result);
          //$_SESSION['admin'] = $user['admin']; 
          $_SESSION['role'] = "admin";
        if((isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == "admin")){
            header("location: Upload.php");
        }else{
            header("location: Home.php");
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is expected ? and what do you mean by same page ? which page ?

Comment: Are you initialized session_start()?

Comment: please do not use this code in production.

Comment: **Every** time you use `'`, you create a string

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$_SESSION['role'] = $user['database-role-column-name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($run){
  $_SESSION['role'] = $user['role'];
   If($user['role'] ==  'admin'){ //admin page}else{//the other page}
}
```

Also try limiting your result on your first query by adding

`LIMIT 0, 1`

Your code is now even  short

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you are session started at the top. Since, you have hardcoded `$_SESSION['role']` variable

```
$_SESSION['role'] = "admin";
```

And, this always be true

```
if((isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == "admin")){
```

You need to use instead

```
$_SESSION['role'] = $user['role'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stored dynamic user role in the session

```
 $_SESSION['role'] = "admin";
```

change to

```
 $_SESSION['role'] = $user['Your_User_Role_coulmn_name'];
```

This script `$user = mysqli_fetch_array( $result);` will return all information about selected user, so if you are storing user role in the same table then you can store the user role value in the session. In this way your if statement will be functional as per requirement.

Also for using session you need add `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION`.

Please check the example

```
session_start();
      if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['surname'];
      $password_hash = md5($password);
      $role;
      if (!empty($username) && (!empty($password))) 
      {
      $query = "SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `staffno` = '$username' AND `password`='$password_hash'";
      $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

          if ($run) {
               $sql = "SELECT users.role FROM users";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                $user = mysqli_fetch_array( $result);
                $_SESSION['role'] = "admin"; // this approach will be always same
                $_SESSION['role'] = $user['Your_User_Role_coulmn_name']; // you need to store dynamic user role into the session
              if((isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == "admin")){
                  header("location: Upload.php");
              }else{
                  header("location: Home.php");
              }
            }
        }

     }
```

Comment: i have tried this but it's still redirecting both users to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you start by changing `$password = $_POST['surname'];` to `$password = $_POST['password'];`  and see if it solve your issue.